# Create MySql Database Backup / Rollback

Tags: php, mysql, backup, restore

I understand that I can use MySql's command `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` to backup a database and rollback when needed.

My question is, would I be able to execute it this way:

```
sql="BACKUP my_db TO DISK my_backup_folder WITH FORMAT #";

if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {    
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
} else {
    $error              = true;
    $message['error']   = true;
    $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
    return json_encode($message);
}
```

And the restoration made in the same fashion:

```
sql="RESTORE DATABASE my_db FROM DISK my_backup_folder WITH FILE #";

if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {    
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
} else {
    $error              = true;
    $message['error']   = true;
    $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
    return json_encode($message);
}
```

And in each case what does `#` stand for, is that `.bak` ? And is there anything else I should add besides what's in there ?

Comment: Have `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` commands been introduced at all?

Comment: Per my answer and @Mchl's comment, these are deprecated commands and probly not the best way to approach a practical backup system for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick peak on the command line shows these are deprecated commands.

```
mysql> help backup; Name: 'BACKUP TABLE' Description: Syntax: BACKUP TABLE tbl_name [, tbl_name] ... TO '/path/to/backup/directory'

*Note*: This statement is deprecated and is removed in MySQL 5.5. As an alternative, mysqldump or mysqlhotcopy can be used instead.
```

I'd say any advice on how to use deprecated commands is a bit of a misnomer.  Take a peak at [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).  There are other options as well such as [LVM snapshots](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/21/using-lvm-for-mysql-backup-and-replication-setup/) etc.

Comment: OK. I've tried to use mysqldump, but it doesn't work on my local server, and I couldn't find why. But now I'm trying another solution, I'm looping through the db and getting all the existing tables and anything inside them. And I'm making files with `fopen` and I'm writing the data into them, also with sql commands like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and other. Anyway, this method I asked didn't work as well.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I would recommend figuring out why mysqldump isn't working.  It's a standard tool and it sounds like you're rewriting it at this point.  I bet in the time you spend getting mysqldump to work you won't be able to replace it with your own stuff.  But who knows, sometimes there is merit to new solutions.

Comment: Indeed. Well, some said that it's because I'm testing in Windows environment, but I have XAAMP which makes all processes work, anything else works I mean but this command. Some say I don't have access to write, but for other procedures which write works. So I couldn't figure out why it isn't working. And I decided to work with what I know it will work.